# Google chrome find next result shortcut?

Tags: google-chrome

What is the shortcut in google chrome after pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to go to next match of the found?

I have tried to use chrome extension keyboardless surfing, and currently using AceJump. Please let me know if there is a shortcut after typing CTRL+F in chrome to go to next search result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to jump to next item.